# listBox выдает null когда нажимаю в "молоко" (Не в элемент "молоко", а просто в пустоту) и из-за этого ошибка

Tags: c#, winforms

Нужно либо задать базовое значение или как-то это исправить. Пробовал, чтобы не выполнялось если null, но все равно ругается. Хелп

System.NullReferenceException: "Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта."
System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.SelectedItem.get вернул null.

```
String[] words = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString().Split(new char[] { ' ' });
```

Быть может я что-то не так написал

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String[] words = null;

if ( listBox1.SelectedItem != null )
{
    words = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString().Split(new char[] { ' ' });
}
```

`listBox1.SelectedItem` не обязан иметь значение. Программа должна быть готова к тому, что ни один элемент не выбран.